# Can I take legal action against a booking agency refusing to refund airport taxes?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, taxes, alitalia

My friend went to Tokyo earlier this year, booking through getaflight.co.uk

However, due to an emergency, he wasn't able to use the second leg of his return trip - as such he is **legally entitled** to a refund of the airport taxes of that leg.

However, despite lots of e-mails (which I have saved), they haven't requested the refund from Alitalia in 3 months, and once when I called to ask them, **they outright lied** by saying that, because one leg of the return trip was used, my friend isn't entitled to a refund of the unused leg.

To clarify, it is **not** stated in their T&C that a fee is charged for tax refunds.

I sent them an E-Mail with high priority just now, and decided that if they don't respond within the next week, I will take legal action against them if possible.

Is there any legal action at all to be taken against an agency refusing to perform a refund the passenger is legally entitled to?

**UPATE**: Okaayy, so now I called Getaflight (they don't seem keen on answering e-mails) who said the refund request had been rejected by Alitalia. I then called Alitalia and got a tax refund "specialist" who said taxes are **always** refundable but that Alitalia never got a request.

I just sent a high-priority message to getaflight, and a copy to Alitalia, confronting them about the fact that once again they're **outright lying** about this whole thing.

Comment: 1) do you have a source for 'legally entitled to'?
2) laws don't have to be stated in the T&Cs to still be true (not saying they're right, just pointing it out)
3) Highly recommend tweeting them. It's still in writing, and because it's public I've had much better response from many companies than going through other communication channels.

Comment: @MarkMayo Airport taxes are paid to an airport for each passenger boarding a given flight. As my friend didn't board the last flight (which the agency acknowledged), the tax for him isn't actually paid to the airport. As such Alitalia is keeping the money for themselves, which is legal as long as a refund isn't requested. However, despite Alitalia agreeing that my friend can get a refund, they're also adamant that it's the agency's job to request it.

Comment: @MarkMayo Getaflight doesn't have Twitter btw

Comment: Maybe a technicality, but you should make sure the actual ticket (not just the reservation) is cancelled or voided with AZ.

Comment: What makes you believe you're entitled to the airport taxes unless the airline specifically allows it? Whatever their expenses are is not your concern as a consumer (by default).

Comment: @JonathanReez Alitalia told me he's entitled to a refund, but the agency hasn't sent them a request

Comment: @Crazydre It probably *is* the agencies job to request it - the sale is theirs, in this case Alitalia is merely the underlying service provider. Airlines refuse all sorts of other interaction with customers who go through an agency - that's the issue with going through an agency, you now have another link in a weak chain, which you have to pray never fails. In this case it's failed - probably because getaflight isn't reputable and wants to pocket the refund themselves.

Comment: @Crazydre as for what legal action could be taken, surely that's better asked on Law stack exchange as legal questions are off topic here ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for advice on suing a company in court, which is not a good fit for this site.